# Solitaire Dreams - Creating a winnable solitaire starting hand

Tags: code-golf, game

It's me. Cave Johnson.

It's May 21st. You are working at Aperture Science, finest company on Earth, and tomorrow we're releasing Version 3.0 of our flagship windowing system (or *WindowS*): CavOS. Unfortunately, tomorrow morning, our chief competitor is releasing Version 3.0 of their *WindowS* too!

It's been leaked to me, Cave Johnson, CEO that the competing *WindowS* has one feature that CavOS lacks: A game of Klondike Solitaire. I, Cave Johnson, am concerned that this omission will lead to drastically lower sales. As such, I, Cave Johnson, have devised a competition between the programming interns to create a game of Solitaire. The programmer whose entry is chosen will get the opportunity to join the exciting GlaDOS AI project.

I, Cave Johnson, has a few requirements:

- Due to the fact that the Software must ship tomorrow, the **shortest program will be chosen** such that it can fit in the spare sectors of the already printed, imaged floppies.
- Don't worry about the gameplay. Our customers have printers don't they? All I need is for your program to **produce a list showing: The order of the cards in the deck, and the contents of each of the 7 piles. The deck will be dealt from the top. The piles will be visible from the bottom. Use the abbreviations H, D, C, S for Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs and Spades. Use the abbreviations K, Q, J, A for King, Queen, Jack, and Ace. Each card should be separated by a space. The first line should show the deck, the second the card of the first and smallest pile, the third the cards of the second pile and so on.** You are welcome to use T instead of 10 if you wish.
- We're making lemonade here - not sucking lemons. I, Cave Johnson, don't like losing, and neither do our customers. **Every game must be winnable**
- **The game must be randomised.** No attempting to encode a single game. There are  7000 trillion possible Klondike hands, and about 90% of them are winnable. I'd be happy with a program that can produce 256 or more different hands. If your language lacks a manner to get random numbers (from a timer or the like), then assume that you can get a seed in a manner appropriate for your language.
- Our customers are reasonably clever. **Assume for winnability that they're playing Draw 3, with no limits on times through the deck**

On behalf of everybody (and everything) at Aperture, I wish you all good luck. We're counting on you.

"*Caroline? How do I shut this damn thing off?*"

---

Out of character: assume the rules of Windows, Draw 3, Not-vegas solitaire. I've attempted to cross every t and dot every i, but ask if you've any questions. Good luck.

Example output:

```
5H AS 7C 8S QH ...    
AH    
JS 10S    
JC JH 7C    
9D AC 8D 7C     
.    
.    
.
```

Comment: Can we use 'T' for 10, so every card is 2 characters?

Comment: I think our customers are clever enough to go for that. I'll add it to the description.

Answer (score 11):

## Brainfuck - <strike>1575</strike> 1365

I am horribly abusing the minimum number of unique deals. This will produce exactly 256 distinct outputs. It accepts one byte of input as its random seed.

```
,>++++[>++++++<-]<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>>>[<+<<+>>>-]>[-]<
<-[>+<-]<[->+>-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<<]>[-]>[-]>[<<<+>>>-]>[-]+[>+<
+++++]>+++++[>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>
>+>>+>>+>>+>>+[<<]>-]>>>>>>>>>+>>+>>+>>+>++++++[>++++>>++++>>++++>>+++
+>>+++>>+++>>+++>>+++>>++++>>++++>>++++>>++++>>+++>>+++>>+++>>+++<<<<<
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<-]>++++>>++++>>++++>>++++>>>>>>>>>>+>>+>>+>>
+>>+>>+>>+>>+[<<]>>[>+<-<+>]>[<+>-]<<+++++++++++[>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+
>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+>>+[<<]>>-]>>>>+>>++++
+>>++++++++++++++++>>>>+>>+++++>>++++++++++++++++>>>>+>>+++++>>+++++++
+++++++++>>>>+>>+++++>>++++++++++++++++>>>>+>>+++++>>++++++++++++++++>
>>>+>>+++++>>++++++++++++++++[<<]<<<<<<[>>>>>>+<<<<<<-]>>>>>>[>[<<+>>-
]<[>+<-]>>[<<+>>-]<-[>+<-]>]>.[-]>.[-]>[[<<<<+>>>>-]>]<<<<<[<<]<++++[>
++++++++<-]>.[-]<<<[>>>+<<<-]>>>[>[<<+>>-]<[>+<-]>>[<<+>>-]<-[>+<-]>]>
.[-]>.[-]>[[<<<<+>>>>-]>]<<++++[>++++++++<-]>.[<<<+>>>-]<<<<<[.[-]>.[-
]>.[<<+>>-]<<<<]>>[>+>++>++<<<-]++++++++++.>>+>+++<.>.<<<.>>----------
-----.+>.<<.>.+>.<<<.>>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<<.>>.>.<<.>++++++++++.>+.
<<.>---------------.+>.<<.>.+>.<<<.>>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>+
++++++++.>++++.<<<.>>---------------.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>.+
>.<<.>.+>.<<<.>>+++++++++.>+++++++++++.<<.>---------------.+>.<<.>.+>.
<<.>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.>.+>.<<.
```

Could definitely be condensed more, but that is kinda the nature of the language. This is quick and dirty, and it works.

Example output (input = 98):

```
8H 9S KS KH KD KC QS QH QD QC JS JH JD JC TS TH TD TC 9H 9D 9C 8S 8D 8C 
AC
2C 3C
4C 5C 6C
7C AD 2D 3D
4D 5D 6D 7D AH
2H 3H 4H 5H 6H 7H
AS 2S 3S 4S 5S 6S 7S
```

It is fairly intuitive that all decks of this format are winnable.

Comment: Wonderful codegolf typical rule bending solution. And it even is Brainfuck - well done!